Need to fix Regex in the PostgreSQL Search
I am in need to use the Word Boundary(\y) as a condition to match the exact word which is been searched as a Query Param. I am writing this regex and executing in PostgreSQL but it is returning FALSE.
text_search_value = "apple." (Which needs to be exactly matched in the {doc_table} which is presented in the code)
My code
vector_split_text = re.sub("\.|\-|/", " ", text_search_value)
text_search_value = re.escape((re.sub("\)",")",re.sub("\(","(",text_search_value))))
converted_part_query = f""""{doc_table}".lni IN (SELECT BTRIM(xxx) FROM "{docsplit_table}" WHERE yyy IN ({all_rcis}) AND doc_text_vector @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', '{vector_split_text}'))"""
               converted_part_query = (
                    "("
                    + converted_part_query
                    + f""" and "{doc_table}".document::text  ~ '\y{text_search_value}\y'"""
                    + ")"
                )

PostgreSQL Query
select 'apple.' ~ '\yapple\.\y'


Expected Result
The Select Query should return TRUE while executing in the PostgreSQL Table with the help of regex fixed.

What is the purpose of replacing ( with again ( and ) with again )? And why do you place \y, a word boundary, after \.? It requires a word character after . Where is your code where you add word boundaries? Hint: you can't use word boundaries here.

If we cannot use the word boundary then how can we do the exact match for the word given as a search string in a Document using .document::text in the Table. I need to search "apple." as a exact search in the Document @WiktorStribiżew

You need to precise the definition of "exact search". So, you do not care if there is a word boundary if the search text does not start/end with a word character? Or do you want to require a special character or start/end of string if the search string starts/ends with a special character? (I take it for granted you want to enforce word boundary check if the search string starts/ends with a word character). Please also confirm you are building the regex dynamically, with code, and please show your code where you are doing that.

Well, I am 99.9% sure the answer is select 'apple.' ~ '(?!\Y\w)apple\.(?!\Y\w)', i.e. search_regex = rf'(?!\Y\w){re.escape(search_string)}(?!\Y\w)' (yeah, "AREs only").

@WiktorStribiżew I have updated the code. Please check

Ok, check if AREs work in that context: rf""" and "{doc_table}".document::text  ~ '(?!\Y\w)apple\.(?!\Y\w)'""".

So, no regex support, right? Please adjust your question and remove the regex tag then. Or remove it altogether in order not to confuse others.

The literal dot \. doesn't belong to the word character class:

A word is defined as a sequence of word characters that is neither preceded nor followed by word characters. A word character is any character belonging to the word character class, that is, any letter, digit, or underscore.

That, combined with two meanings of \y:









\y
matches only at the beginning or end of a word



And the note under the table this is from:

A word is defined as in the specification of [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] above.

Means your pattern expects another word to start at the second \y.
demo at db<>fiddle
select 'apple.' ~ '\yapple\.\y';









False



select 'apple.plum' ~ '\yapple\.\y'









True



If you're looking for an apple followed by a dot and not preceded or followed by any word characters, use '\yapple\.\Y'. Or a '\yapple\y' if you don't really need the dot.
I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve exactly but if you're trying to wrap user input, you might need to trim() non-word characters before adding an \m on the front and an \M at the end to avoid this, or switch between \y and \Y based on the leading/trailing character, if you don't want to match anything with another word glued to it.

I am in need to search "apple." as an exact match with the Text Vectors available in my DB. So that only I am using the above query directly in postgreSQL to ensure whether it returns true

You mean text vectors as in text search vectors, tsvector type? If that's the case, I'd post a new question where you lead with that. That's matched with @@ not ~. The tsquery syntax isn't the same and it's a whole different thing.

I'm sorry, I might be confused, but if you're using a Python regex command, \y is not a word boundary. Instead, you're using the literal "y" letter to match your word. You should use \b for a word boundary. The correct regex syntax should look like the following:
select 'apple.' ~ '\bapple\b'
made with regex101

"if you're using a Python regex command": well, they don't. They wrote "executing in PostgreSQL", as also shown in the code select 'apple.' ~ '\yapple\.\y'.
